# Receive events from AMQP with Axon 4

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, amqp, axon

I am trying to send messages via rabbitmq to an axon4 spring boot based system. The message is received but no events are triggered. I am very sure I am missing an essential part, but up to now I wasn't able to figure it out.

Here the relevant part of my application.yml

```
axon:
    amqp:
        exchange: axon.fanout
        transaction-mode: publisher_ack
    # adding the following lines changed nothing
    eventhandling:
        processors:
            amqpEvents:
                source: in.queue
                mode: subscribing
spring:
    rabbitmq:
        username: rabbit
        password: rabbit
```

From the docs I found that I am supposed to create a SpringAMQPMessageSource bean:

```java
import com.rabbitmq.client.Channel;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.axonframework.extensions.amqp.eventhandling.AMQPMessageConverter;
import org.axonframework.extensions.amqp.eventhandling.spring.SpringAMQPMessageSource;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.Message;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.RabbitListener;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Slf4j
@Configuration
public class AxonConfig {

    @Bean
    SpringAMQPMessageSource inputMessageSource(final AMQPMessageConverter messageConverter) {
        return new SpringAMQPMessageSource(messageConverter) {
            @RabbitListener(queues = "in.queue")
            @Override
            public void onMessage(final Message message, final Channel channel) {
                log.debug("received external message: {}, channel: {}", message, channel);
                super.onMessage(message, channel);
            }
        };
    }

}
```

If I send a message to the queue from the rabbitmq admin panel I see the log:

`AxonConfig  : received external message: (Body:'[B@13f7aeef(byte[167])' MessageProperties [headers={}, contentLength=0, receivedDeliveryMode=NON_PERSISTENT, redelivered=false, receivedExchange=, receivedRoutingKey=in.queue, deliveryTag=2, consumerTag=amq.ctag-xi34jwHHA__xjENSteX5Dw, consumerQueue=in.queue]), channel: Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://rabbit@127.0.0.1:5672/,1), conn: Proxy@11703cc8 Shared Rabbit Connection: SimpleConnection@581cb879 [delegate=amqp://rabbit@127.0.0.1:5672/, localPort= 58614]`

Here the Aggregate that should receive the events:

```java
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.axonframework.commandhandling.CommandHandler;
import org.axonframework.config.ProcessingGroup;
import org.axonframework.eventsourcing.EventSourcingHandler;
import org.axonframework.modelling.command.AggregateIdentifier;
import org.axonframework.spring.stereotype.Aggregate;
import pm.mbo.easyway.api.app.order.commands.ConfirmOrderCommand;
import pm.mbo.easyway.api.app.order.commands.PlaceOrderCommand;
import pm.mbo.easyway.api.app.order.commands.ShipOrderCommand;
import pm.mbo.easyway.api.app.order.events.OrderConfirmedEvent;
import pm.mbo.easyway.api.app.order.events.OrderPlacedEvent;
import pm.mbo.easyway.api.app.order.events.OrderShippedEvent;

import static org.axonframework.modelling.command.AggregateLifecycle.apply;

@ProcessingGroup("amqpEvents")
@Slf4j
@Aggregate
public class OrderAggregate {

    @AggregateIdentifier
    private String orderId;
    private boolean orderConfirmed;

    @CommandHandler
    public OrderAggregate(final PlaceOrderCommand command) {
        log.debug("command: {}", command);
        apply(new OrderPlacedEvent(command.getOrderId(), command.getProduct()));
    }

    @CommandHandler
    public void handle(final ConfirmOrderCommand command) {
        log.debug("command: {}", command);
        apply(new OrderConfirmedEvent(orderId));
    }

    @CommandHandler
    public void handle(final ShipOrderCommand command) {
        log.debug("command: {}", command);
        if (!orderConfirmed) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot ship an order which has not been confirmed yet.");
        }
        apply(new OrderShippedEvent(orderId));
    }

    @EventSourcingHandler
    public void on(final OrderPlacedEvent event) {
        log.debug("event: {}", event);
        this.orderId = event.getOrderId();
        orderConfirmed = false;
    }

    @EventSourcingHandler
    public void on(final OrderConfirmedEvent event) {
        log.debug("event: {}", event);
        orderConfirmed = true;
    }

    @EventSourcingHandler
    public void on(final OrderShippedEvent event) {
        log.debug("event: {}", event);
        orderConfirmed = true;
    }

    protected OrderAggregate() {
    }

}
```

So the problem is that the messages are received by the system but no events are triggered. The content of the messages seem to be irrelevant. Whatever I send to the queue I only get a log message from my onMessage method.

JavaDoc of SpringAMQPMessageSource says this:

```
/**
 * MessageListener implementation that deserializes incoming messages and forwards them to one or more event processors.
 * <p>
 * The SpringAMQPMessageSource must be registered with a Spring MessageListenerContainer and forwards each message
 * to all subscribed processors.
 * <p>
 * Note that the Processors must be subscribed before the MessageListenerContainer is started. Otherwise, messages will
 * be consumed from the AMQP Queue without any processor processing them.
 *
 * @author Allard Buijze
 * @since 3.0
 */
```

But up to now I couldn't find out where or how to register it.

The axon.eventhandling entries in my config and @ProcessingGroup("amqpEvents") in my Aggregate are already from testing. But having those entries in or not made no difference at all. Also tried without the mode=subscribing.

Exact versions: Spring Boot 2.1.4, Axon 4.1.1, axon-amqp-spring-boot-autoconfigure 4.1

Any help or hints highly appreciated.

---

Update 23.04.19:

I tried to write my own class like this:

```
import com.rabbitmq.client.Channel;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.axonframework.common.Registration;
import org.axonframework.eventhandling.EventMessage;
import org.axonframework.extensions.amqp.eventhandling.AMQPMessageConverter;
import org.axonframework.messaging.SubscribableMessageSource;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.Message;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.RabbitListener;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.api.ChannelAwareMessageListener;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList;
import java.util.function.Consumer;

@Slf4j
@Component
public class RabbitMQSpringAMQPMessageSource implements ChannelAwareMessageListener, SubscribableMessageSource<EventMessage<?>> {

    private final List<Consumer<List<? extends EventMessage<?>>>> eventProcessors = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();
    private final AMQPMessageConverter messageConverter;

    @Autowired
    public RabbitMQSpringAMQPMessageSource(final AMQPMessageConverter messageConverter) {
        this.messageConverter = messageConverter;
    }

    @Override
    public Registration subscribe(final Consumer<List<? extends EventMessage<?>>> messageProcessor) {
        eventProcessors.add(messageProcessor);
        log.debug("subscribe to: {}", messageProcessor);
        return () -> eventProcessors.remove(messageProcessor);
    }

    @RabbitListener(queues = "${application.queues.in}")
    @Override
    public void onMessage(final Message message, final Channel channel) {
        log.debug("received external message: {}, channel: {}", message, channel);
        log.debug("eventProcessors: {}", eventProcessors);
        if (!eventProcessors.isEmpty()) {
            messageConverter.readAMQPMessage(message.getBody(), message.getMessageProperties().getHeaders())
                            .ifPresent(event -> eventProcessors.forEach(
                                ep -> ep.accept(Collections.singletonList(event))
                            ));
        }
    }

}
```

The result is the same and the log now proofs that the eventProcessors are just empty.

```
eventProcessors: []
```

### So the question is, how to register the event processors correctly. Is there a way how to do that properly with spring?

Update2:

Also no luck with this:

```
@Slf4j
@Component("rabbitMQSpringAMQPMessageSource")
public class RabbitMQSpringAMQPMessageSource extends SpringAMQPMessageSource {

    @Autowired
    public RabbitMQSpringAMQPMessageSource(final AMQPMessageConverter messageConverter) {
        super(messageConverter);
    }

    @RabbitListener(queues = "${application.queues.in}")
    @Override
    public void onMessage(final Message message, final Channel channel) {

        try {
            final var eventProcessorsField = this.getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredField("eventProcessors");
            eventProcessorsField.setAccessible(true);
            final var eventProcessors = (List<Consumer<List<? extends EventMessage<?>>>>) eventProcessorsField.get(this);
            log.debug("eventProcessors: {}", eventProcessors);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        log.debug("received message: message={}, channel={}", message, channel);
        super.onMessage(message, channel);
    }

}
```

```
axon:
    eventhandling:
        processors:
            amqpEvents:
                source: rabbitMQSpringAMQPMessageSource
                mode: SUBSCRIBING
```

Registering it programmatically in addition to above also didn't help:

```
    @Autowired
    void configure(EventProcessingModule epm,
                   RabbitMQSpringAMQPMessageSource rabbitMessageSource) {
        epm.registerSubscribingEventProcessor("rabbitMQSpringAMQPMessageSource", c -> rabbitMessageSource);
        epm.assignProcessingGroup("amqpEvents", "rabbitMQSpringAMQPMessageSource");// this line also made no difference
    }
```

Of course @ProcessingGroup("amqpEvents") is in place in my class that contains the @EventSourcingHandler annotated methods.

---

Update 25.4.19:

see accepted answer from Allard. Thanks a lot pointing me at the mistake I made: I missed that EventSourcingHandler don't receive messages from outside. This is for projections. Not for distributing Aggregates! *ups*
Here the config/classes that are receiving events from rabbitmq now:

```
axon:
    eventhandling:
        processors:
            amqpEvents:
                source: rabbitMQSpringAMQPMessageSource
                mode: SUBSCRIBING
```

```
import com.rabbitmq.client.Channel;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.axonframework.extensions.amqp.eventhandling.AMQPMessageConverter;
import org.axonframework.extensions.amqp.eventhandling.spring.SpringAMQPMessageSource;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.Message;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.RabbitListener;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Slf4j
@Component("rabbitMQSpringAMQPMessageSource")
public class RabbitMQSpringAMQPMessageSource extends SpringAMQPMessageSource {

    @Autowired
    public RabbitMQSpringAMQPMessageSource(final AMQPMessageConverter messageConverter) {
        super(messageConverter);
    }

    @RabbitListener(queues = "${application.queues.in}")
    @Override
    public void onMessage(final Message message, final Channel channel) {
        log.debug("received message: message={}, channel={}", message, channel);
        super.onMessage(message, channel);
    }

}
```

```
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.axonframework.config.ProcessingGroup;
import org.axonframework.eventhandling.EventHandler;
import org.axonframework.queryhandling.QueryHandler;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import pm.mbo.easyway.api.app.order.events.OrderConfirmedEvent;
import pm.mbo.easyway.api.app.order.events.OrderPlacedEvent;
import pm.mbo.easyway.api.app.order.events.OrderShippedEvent;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

@Slf4j
@ProcessingGroup("amqpEvents")
@Service
public class OrderedProductsEventHandler {

    private final Map<String, OrderedProduct> orderedProducts = new HashMap<>();

    @EventHandler
    public void on(OrderPlacedEvent event) {
        log.debug("event: {}", event);
        String orderId = event.getOrderId();
        orderedProducts.put(orderId, new OrderedProduct(orderId, event.getProduct()));
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void on(OrderConfirmedEvent event) {
        log.debug("event: {}", event);
        orderedProducts.computeIfPresent(event.getOrderId(), (orderId, orderedProduct) -> {
            orderedProduct.setOrderConfirmed();
            return orderedProduct;
        });
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void on(OrderShippedEvent event) {
        log.debug("event: {}", event);
        orderedProducts.computeIfPresent(event.getOrderId(), (orderId, orderedProduct) -> {
            orderedProduct.setOrderShipped();
            return orderedProduct;
        });
    }

    @QueryHandler
    public List<OrderedProduct> handle(FindAllOrderedProductsQuery query) {
        log.debug("query: {}", query);
        return new ArrayList<>(orderedProducts.values());
    }

}
```

I removed the @ProcessingGroup from my Aggregate of course.

My logs:

```
RabbitMQSpringAMQPMessageSource : received message: ... 
OrderedProductsEventHandler : event: OrderShippedEvent...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Axon, Aggregates do not receive events from "outside". The Event Handlers inside Aggregates (more specifically, they are EventSourcingHandlers) only handle events that have been published by that same aggregate instance, so that it can reconstruct its prior state.

It is only external event handlers, for example the ones that update projections, that will receive events from external sources.

For that to work, your application.yml should mention the bean name as a processors' source instead of the queue name. So in your first example:

```
    eventhandling:
        processors:
            amqpEvents:
                source: in.queue
                mode: subscribing
```

Should become:

```
    eventhandling:
        processors:
            amqpEvents:
                source: inputMessageSource
                mode: subscribing
```

But again, this only works for event handlers defined on components, not on Aggregates.

Comment: Thx Allard! That helped. Found the mistake with source already, but changing the name didn't help too. My MessageSource was already correct but I was missing that Aggregates/EventSouringHandler don't receive messages from outside. And thinking about it, that makes absolute sense.Moving the annotation @ProcessingGroup("amqpEvents") over a class with @EventHandler methods immediately worked.